# How to make the "P" and "e" hollow?

Tags: inkscape

I have a slight of a problem here.

This is the logo I would like to convert from 2d to 3d

[image]

After that I followed all the instructions as per described in the following link :

http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-3D-print-from-a-2D-drawing/#step2

However as I opened my file in OpenSCAD, the "P" and "e" were not hollowed out :

[image]

Please help a student out here. It is my very first time posting here and also using Inkscape and OpenSCAD.

Thank you very much for all the help.

Good day

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the original file is a vector based file (.eps .ai etc.) and that you're working with a 'compound path'. If it is a pixel based file (.jpg .bitmap .tiff) then it's probably a 'tracing' error. (an algorithm that converts bitmap files to vector)

Good luck!

Comment: The image is in .jpeg format. So how do I correct on this tracing error?

Answer (score 1):

Just in few minutes you can finish this task. You can download the Inkscape program for free. Then create new sheet, import the bitmap and vectorize it using edge detection (using online tools it is also not difficult, but for safety reasons I would recommend to avoid make it that way). Save it as a file with svg extension, import it to OpenCAD and retry the operation.